cómo configurar cors en @mswjs/http-middleware
Estoy tratando de correr un servidor de mocks para mi aplicación react y no sé como resolver el error de CORS que me está dando.
Usé el código de ejemplo de su github para hacer este código inicial:
import { http, HttpResponse } from 'msw'
import { createMiddleware } from '@mswjs/http-middleware'

const app = express()

app.use(
  createMiddleware(
    http.get('/api/products', () => {
      return HttpResponse.json([{
                id: 1,
                name: 'Gorra café',
                price: 10.99,
                image: 'FOTOSURBAN-28.JPG',
                description: 'Description 1',
            }])
    }),
  ),
)

app.use(9090)

Intentos
Me hice un endpoint de OPTIONS, sigue dando error de CORS
http.options('/api/products', () => {
    return new Response(null, {
        status: 200,
        headers: {
            Allow: 'GET,HEAD,POST',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization'
        },
    })
}),

Puse los headers manualmente
http.get('/api/products', () => {
    return new Response(null, {
        status: 200,
        headers: {
            Allow: 'GET,HEAD,POST',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body:[{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Gorra café',
            price: 10.99,
            image: 'FOTOSURBAN-28.JPG',
            description: 'Description 1',
        }]
    })
})

Mi código fuente completo lo pueden hallar en https://github.com/javatlacati/ecommercemocks por si alguien tiene idea de algún experimento que a mí no se me haya ocurrido o quiere revisar algo es detalle

¿Has intentado consumir dicho servidor des otra aplicación como curl o incluso con Postman? ¿Da el mismo error? Siendo que es una aplicación de Express, podrías usar el paquete cors y probar una vez configurado en tu servidor Express. Toma en cuenta que es probable que la ruta en la que implementas las cabeceras nisiquiera sean consumidas ya que Express (realmente NodeJS) podría estar bloqueando antes la petición. Es lo que el paquete cors te ayuda a corregir.

@MauricioContreras, efectivamente desde postman se consume sin problemas. Cuando hace tiempo intenté conectarme a AWS desde Angular me daba error de CORS porque no tenía el endpoint OPTIONS, por eso pensé que sería alguna cosa del framework, deja intento ponerle la dependencia que indicas

Olvodaba que Postman nunca te da error de CORS, por lo cual no es fiable para dicha prueba.
